# Linking email button to a column in the DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i have a Covid email message we are sending to our business customers which will have a button that they can click which will take them to a landing page. I have created this landing page in Cloud pages.
I am sending this email to a DE with the columns below.

[image]

For customers that click on this button i would like the Clicked column to be updated with a 'Yes'

What would be the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you built the landing page in Marketing Cloud, you can use the AMPSCript function [UpdateData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatedata.htm) to update that column.

Comment: Thank you. how do i reference the button that is clicked with the Cloud page ID

Comment: pass it as a parameter in the URL - e.g. `href="https://www.mySite.com?btn=Sample"` and then you can collect this via RequestParameter() or similar function on the Cloud page and add it into your upsert